# List of objects with variable number of fields

Tags: c#

I have a class as some relational data source which I can't change

```
public class Reader
{
    public int FieldCount;
    public void Parse(string query) { } // Makes query
    public bool Read() { return true; } //Reads current row
    public void GetValues(object[] value) { } //Populates an array of objects with the column values of the current row.
    public string GetName(int i) { return ""; } //Gets the name of the specified column
}
```

I process result as strings like this

```
        var reader = new Reader();
        reader.Parse("select field1, field2 from tbl");
        var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.GetValues(values);
            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                //process data here
                Console.WriteLine("Field {0}  Value {1}", reader.GetName(i), (string)values[i]);
            }
        }
```

I want to make it more abstract to move it to a method with result of convenient format. Perhaps move result into list of some object instances with appropriate fields. Since I specify the query, I can provide field names as parameter if it helps. The data type doesn't matter, I want everything as strings.

Something like this

```
        var reader = new Reader();
        var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        var fields = new string[] { "field1", "field2"};
        var result = new List<fields>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.GetValues(values);
            result.Add(values.Select(s => new fields { "reader.GetName(0)" = (string)values[0], "reader.GetName(1)" = (string)values[1]}));

        }
        //process data here
```

Comment: What good does calling `reader.GetValues(values)` do?

Comment: Your title and code suggest that the number of fields may change, but the text suggest they are fixed, or at least that there is a upper limit. So what is it? And is it possible for the type and meaning of the values to change?

Comment: How are your data objects defined? Are you able to determine their name and data type?

Comment: The number of fields is variable in sense that `Read()` function reads as many columns as I specify beforehand and I can provide same list of columns at getting the result

Comment: So, you mean like reading from a database? Is it actually a database? I'm just trying to work out if you're (needlessly) reinventing EF/Dapper. Perhaps providing an IDataReader abstraction would allow you to use an existing "database" technology with whatever data source this is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you write an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ReadAll(this Reader reader, params string [] fields)
{
    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    var names = values.Select((_, i) => reader.GetName(i)).ToArray();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.GetValues(values);
        yield return
            names
                .Zip(values, (name, value) => (name, value))
                .Where(x => fields.Contains(x.name))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.value);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> fields = reader.ReadAll("field1", "field2");
```